# Error logging in NiFi with PutSQL processors

Tags: logging, apache-nifi

I want to insert SQL rows into `my_logging_table` as a log whenever a NiFi Put-SQL-processor in my pipeline fails. So far I had to create another logging-`PutSQL` processor for **every** pipeline-processor which have the following `sql-statement`:

```
insert into schema.my_logging_table values
('Failed-NiFi-processor-name', 'failed', current_timestamp)
```

This obviously leads to double the number of NiFi processors as each has to have their own "logging-putsql-processor" so that the correct processor name can be logged.

Is there a way to have my pipeline-putsql-processors update a flowfile property on fail (Im thinking of passing on the name of the processor)?

This way I could route all failures to a single logging-putsql-processor which reads the failing processor's name from the file property and insert the row into the database.
I noticed the "update_attribute" processor, but I would have to build one of them for every processor as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to stick an UpdateAttribute on the Failure branch, not all processors write failure attributes. You'll see what attributes they write in the processor docs - see the Writes Attributes section for [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/)

Alternatively, you could

1. Create a flow to parse nifi-app.log and hunt for the errors
2. Create a [SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.reporting.SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask/index.html) flow that captures all bulletins, sends them to an RPG, filters for PutSQL failures, sends to DB, etc.